# Not able to copy paste a section of image in P5.js

Tags: p5.js

I have been working on a project in which I have to select an area of image and then use CTRL+C and CTRL+V to copy and paste the selected area. I have tried creating a buffer using createGraphics() but did not work. I have also tried getting pixels one by one and creating image but that is not working either. Can somebody help? Below is my code.

```
    if (this.isCtrlPressed == true && p5.key == 'v') {
        let img = p5.createImage(this.dw, this.dh);
        p5.draw = () => {
          img.loadPixels();
          for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(this.sw); i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < parseInt(this.sh); j++) {
              img.set(i, j, p5.get(i, j));
            }
          }

          img.updatePixels();
          p5.stroke(255);
          p5.image(img, 10, 10);
          p5.noFill();
          p5.rect(p5.mouseX, p5.mouseY, 10, 10);
          return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not too far off.

Bare in mind that you can also call [`get()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/get) with `width, height` arguments, not just the first two (`x, y`): this will make it easy to copy a section of the image.

The `p5.Graphics` you get using `createGraphics()` is handy indeed.

Remember to store the selection rectangle properties (x, y, width, height) to copy the image in the first place.

Here's a very rough sketch based on the [CreateImage p5.js example](https://editor.p5js.org/p5/sketches/Image:_Create_Image):

```js
/*
 * @name Create Image
 * @description The createImage() function provides a fresh buffer of pixels to
 * play with. This example creates an image gradient.
 */
let img; // Declare variable 'img'.

// copy/paste selection rectangle
let selection = {x:0, y:0, w:0, h:0};
// p5.Image from main image using selection
let clipboard;
// where to paste the clipboard p5.Image
let pasteBuffer;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(720, 400);
  img = createImage(230, 230);
  img.loadPixels();
  for (let x = 0; x < img.width; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < img.height; y++) {
      let a = map(y, 0, img.height, 255, 0);
      img.set(x, y, [0, 153, 204, a]);
    }
  }
  img.updatePixels();
  // selection drawing style
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  // setup buffer to paste into
  pasteBuffer = createGraphics(width, height);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  // render original image
  image(img, 0, 0);
  // render pasted graphics
  image(pasteBuffer, 0, 0);
  // render selection rectangle
  rect(selection.x, selection.y, selection.w, selection.h);
}

function mousePressed(){
  // store selection start
  selection.x = mouseX;
  selection.y = mouseY;
}

function mouseDragged(){
  // update selection dimension as the difference between the current mouse coordinates and the previous ones (selection x, y)
  selection.w = mouseX - selection.x;
  selection.h = mouseY - selection.y;
}

function keyPressed(keyEvent){
  if (key == 'c') {
    console.log("copy image", selection);
    // use get() to "clone" a subsection of the main image
    clipboard = img.get(selection.x, selection.y, selection.w, selection.h);
  }
  
  if (key == 'v') {
    console.log("paste image");
    if(clipboard){
      // simply render the clipboard image 
      pasteBuffer.image(clipboard, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Note the above isn't perfect (e.g. you need to use `abs()` to handle making selections from right to left, not just left to right), but hopefully it illustrates the usage of a selection rectangle, copying pixels and "pasting"/rendering them into a buffer.

Speaking of copying pixels, an alternative option could be using a `p5.Image` (using `createImage()` instead of `createGraphics()`) and [`copy()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/copy) (instead of `buffer.image()`) (and you'd use the selection rectangle properties to know from where to where to paste pixels).